# Смотрю обучающее видео не срабатывает orderBy в Vue js

Tags: vue.js

> не срабатывает   orderBy в Vue js

```
<div id="currency_doll"><ul><li v-for="item in array | orderBy 'age'">{{item.name}}, {{item.age}}</li></ul></div>`

<script>
new Vue ({
      el: "#currency_doll",
      data: {
        sum: 501,
        symbol : '$',
        array: [
        {
          name: "Иван",
          age: 46
        },
        {
          name: "Лариса",
          age: 32
        },
        {
          name: "Виктор",
          age: 12
        }
        ]
      }
    })
</script>
```

В чём причина?

Comment: наверное, очень старое видео Вы смотрите. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512585/vue-js-cant-orderby-in-v-for

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что я смотрю версию 1 (видео 16 года), а подключил версию 2.